# Ways to align divs side by side in another div

Tags: html, css

I used 4 different ways to align nested divs side by side. I expect these 4 ways to be correct, but only one is working (float). Can somebody explain why ?

```
<div style="background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <span style="background-color:red;width:70%;height:100%;"></span>
    <span style="background-color:blue;width:30%;height:100%;"></span>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="background-color:red;width:70%;height:100%;display:inline"></div>
    <div style="background-color:blue;width:30%;height:100%;display:inline"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="background-color:red;width:70%;height:100%;float:left"></div>
    <div style="background-color:blue;width:30%;height:100%;float:left"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px;">
    <div style="background-color:red;width:70%;height:100%;display:inline-block"></div>
    <div style="background-color:blue;width:30%;height:100%;display:inline-block"></div>
</div>
```

[Or JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKScJ/75/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with my question ? I've negative votes and I don't know why ? This question was never asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A `<span>` isn't a block element, so it doesn't have width and height.
2. The same goes for `<div>`'s set to `display: inline`.
3. This works as you expected.
4. You can remove the white space between the div's to make it work. Elements set to `inline-block` have a space between them just like two words would. That's why you could also set `font-size: 0;` and it would work.
5. You could do the same as #3 but with `position: absolute`.

Comment: Perfect. I was expected this kind of answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

this is painfull... but the first one, the span is an inline element, so is the second set the div that has the `style="inline"` attached to it. This means they wont accept any height or width styles, as they are not blocks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first example uses SPANs, SPANs are an inline element and therefore you cannot apply a height or width to them.

Your second example, you are changing a BLOCK element (DIV) but changing it into an inline element cannot apply a height or width to them.

Floating an element removes it from the flow of the document, so different rules apply, and you can apply width and height

The last example will work if you remove the white space between the 2 nested DIVS:

```
<div style="background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px;">
<div style="background-color:red;width:70%;height:100%;display:inline-block"></div><div style="background-color:blue;width:30%;height:100%;display:inline-block"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kKScJ/76/

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

give on div inline `style` code as `float:left;`

it give as align div all are one side one

```
<div style="background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px;float:left;">
   <span style="background-color:red;width:70%;height:100%;"></span>
   <span style="background-color:blue;width:30%;height:100%;"></span>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div style="background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px;float:left;">
    <span style="background-color:red;width:70%;height:100%;float:left;"></span>
    <span style="background-color:blue;width:30%;height:100%;float:left;"></span>
</div>
```